# CSS3 Animation - How to hide an Animation until it enters a Div

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm sure it's a simple answer, but I'm trying to figure out how to hide the animation below: until it enters the div.

```
.slideInDown {
-webkit-animation-name: slideInDown;
-moz-animation-name: slideInDown;
-o-animation-name: slideInDown;
animation-name: slideInDown;

   }
@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
}
```

I want the final to look similar to the first animation in the center of this page: www.laracasey.com.

Thanks!

Comment: We really don't have enough information. Perhaps you could provide us with a working version in JSFiddle or Codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS3, we can add an effect when changing from one style to another, without using Flash animations or JavaScripts.

To do this, you must specify two things:

Specify the CSS property you want to add an effect to and Specify the duration of the effect.

For example:

```
<style> 
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
transition:width 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */
}

div:hover
{
width:300px;
}
```

[Try it yourself.](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1) You can see more in [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Or if you want to use `JQuery`. Here is an example :

```
$("div").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("slideInDown");
});
```

**In your case** :

I create the div the simulate your situation:

```
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
}
```

Simply declare the class and animation name :

```
.sideInDown{
    animation:slideInLeft 5s;
-webkit-animation:slideInLeft 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Create the keyframs :

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
}
```

Finally, use the `JQuery` to add a class when a mouseover event happens:

```
$("div").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("sideInDown");
});
```

You can see how it acts from [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ss5fF/)

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this one?
http://fiddle.jshell.net/sijav/PjEb5/ 
you need to place your thing to animate in the div and make the overflow of that div as overflow:hidden
hope it helps